# Hide plugin from admin bar & plugin list

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to hide the following item from the following sections:

Admin bar: ID = wp-admin-bar-nitropack-top-menu

Plugin list: data-slug="nitropack"

I have tried these methods, but can not get it to work. Maybe i have the wrong IDs/Slugs?

Methods: https://divi.space/wordpress-and-divi-code-snippets/hide-any-plugin-from-the-wordpress-dashboard/

Would really appreciate some help, since a customer should not be able to change the settings within this plugin!

Best regards,
Isac

Answer (score 0):

The css way

```
<style>

a[data-slug="nitropack"] { //hides all a href's with that data slug
display:none;
} 

</style>
```

normally if its an wp admin menu you would do something like this:

```
//remove admin page item
function edit_admin_menus() {
remove_menu_page("index.php"); //Dashboard
remove_menu_page("itsec"); // wp-admin.php?page=itsec use this "itsec"
}
add_action("admin_menu", "edit_admin_menus");
```

or you need to remove admin bar item

```
//remove tool bar item
function remove_toolbar_node($wp_admin_bar) {
    // replace 'updraft_admin_node' with your node id "nitropack" something
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node("avia");
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node("updates");
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu("wp-logo");
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu("themes");
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu("widgets");
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu("dashboard");
//$wp_admin_bar->remove_node("updraft_admin_node");
}
add_action("admin_bar_menu", "remove_toolbar_node", 999);
```

FYI, since you need to block access to the plugin you'll need to add a redirect based on member role. The customer may know the actual url and can still access the page.

```
//Admin or Editor role check, if else send to alt url
function block_pages_for_user() {
  $blocked_pages = is_page('slug');
  $url = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if( !current_user_can('administrator') && !current_user_can('editor') && !current_user_can('subscriber') && $blocked_pages ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 );
    exit;
} 
}
add_action( 'wp', 'block_pages_for_user', 8 );
```